# Use forge.tabs.open on a URL returned from an API call

Tags: trigger.io

I'm hitting an API that return a list of URLs, so I'm looking to iterate through them, generate links, and let the user browse to those links. I think I'm supposed to use forge.tabs.open to create a Modal view when the user taps a link. Here's the code:

```
$("#feed").append('<p><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="viewLink('+item.data.url+', "'+item.data.title+'");" class="viewlink">'+item.data.title+'</a></p>');
```

And the viewLink function:

```
var viewLink = function(linkurl, linktitle) {
    forge.logging.log(linkurl);
    forge.logging.log(linktitle);

    forge.tabs.openWithOptions({
        url: linkurl,
        title: linktitle,
        buttonText: "close"
    });
};
```

It doesn't work on iOS and doesn't generate an error. When I run it in my browser, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Will try it tonight and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger.io code you posted looks fine to me.  When I see the "unexpected token" syntax error I immediately think: single quote, double quote, or character encoding.

Do any of the linktitle's have a "weird" character?  Maybe you need to escape or encodeURIComponent or decodeURIComponent it?

Comment: Turns out that I need to wrap linkurl in single quotes, like this: 'linkurl'. I basically added linkurl = "'"+linkurl+"'"; to my code and now the modal appears, but produces an error.